# Button to Add Cell with textField Text to Table Xcode/Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My question relates specifically to the following set of actions: I would like a user to be able to input text into a textField, press a button, then have that text transferred into a cell that is then newly populated in a table.

I have one view controller with a text field, button, and table objects. I also have an array that stores each string as the user enters the text, and my code looks as follows:

UPDATE 1: added "self.taskTable.delegate = self" and "self.taskTable.dataSource = self" as suggested in the comments.

UPDATE 2: forgot to add the identifier in the Storyboard editor, code is now functional, thank you everyone! The code is now as follows:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var taskTable: UITableView!
var taskArray : NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray() //Could be a non-NS as well

@IBAction func addTask(sender: AnyObject) {
    //Print to alert we entered method
    print("task submitted")
    //Get input from text field
    let input = textField.text
    //Add object to array, reload table
    self.taskArray.addObject(input!)
    self.taskTable.reloadData()
}//addTask

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.taskTable.delegate = self
    self.taskTable.dataSource = self
    print("application finished loading")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.taskArray.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.taskTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.taskArray.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as? String
    return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: well the code I presented currently doesn't work, so I'm wondering if there are any changes I could make to get it functional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you haven't actually made your ViewController the UITableViewDelegate or UITableViewDataSource.  In your Storyboard, right click your UITableView and make sure that delegate and datasource are set.  If they aren't, drag from the circle next to each one and connect it to the ViewController.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the only issue is now the one in the below comment thread.

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the delegate references in your `viewDidLoad()`

add the following:

```
self.taskTable.delegate = self
self.taskTable.dataSource = self
```

Edit: Typo

Comment: Interesting, it presents the following error: "Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'datasource'"

Comment: @jb990 it should be self.taskTable.dataSource with a capital S

Comment: Gotcha. Cleared those errors up. Only issue now is a runtime error at: "let cell:UITableViewCell = self.taskTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")!" claiming a value of nil was found

Comment: That one is just tableView.dequeuReusable..... Etc instead of self.taskTable.dequeue.....